# How to calculate the std in scala with high order functions

Tags: scala, math, lazy-evaluation

I am new to scala.
Lately I have tried to write some math functions, but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.math.{pow, sqrt}

object HikeStatProcessor {

  def mean(list: List[Double]): Double = {
    sum(list, value => value) / list.size
  }

  def std(list: List[Double]): Double = {
    val means: Double = mean(list)
    sqrt(pow(sum(list, (head: Double) => head - means), 2) / list.size)
  }

  private def sum(list: List[Double],
                  operation: Double => Double): Double = {
    @tailrec
    def innerCalc(xs: List[Double], accu: Double): Double = {
      if (xs.isEmpty) return accu
      println(accu + operation(xs.head))
      innerCalc(xs.tail, accu + operation(xs.head))
    }
   innerCalc(list, 0)
  }

}

val a  = HikeStatProcessor.std(List(1, 2, 3))
```

Could you please provide a fix for the above code and a brief explanation of what I was doing wrong?

Comment: You probably should explain why exactly you think that the code is wrong. What was the input, what was the expected/unexpected output?

Comment: The problem is probably the use of `return`, you should [**NEVER USE RTEURN IN SCALA**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html)

Comment: The `return` keyword is not the problem, it's an ordinary arithmetic bug.

Comment: I was trying to calculate the standard deviation for a given list (population). The expected output for the above snippet is 0.8164

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks all for the answers.
I solved the issue by changing the `def std` to:

```
def std(list: List[Double]): Double = {
    val means: Double = mean(list)
    sqrt( sum(list, (head: Double) => pow(head - means, 2)) / (list.size - 1) )
  }
```

The issue was caused by the fact that I did not evaluate the pow 2 within my anonymous function.

Comment: Why the downote? This is actually the answer to the issue (calculating the standard deviation in scala).

Answer (score 3):

Consider this statement: `sum(list, (head: Double) => head - means)`. Let's break it down into smaller steps.

```
sum(list       , (head: Double) => head - means)
sum(List(1,2,3),             x  => x - 2)
sum(List(1-2, 2-2, 3-2))
          -1 +  0 +  1 = 0
```

If you subtract the average from each element, the sum is always going to be zero (or close to it). What was your intention?